# Composition of continuous function and Riemann Integrable function is Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to check if this proof is correct.
Statement: Let $f:[a,b] \to  \mathbb R $ be Riemann integrable
Let $\phi :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous, then the composition $\phi \circ f$ is Riemann integrable.

My proof is a lot shorter than the one provided in the note so wanted to check:
So f is a continuous function on a closed bounded interval therefore it is bounded, so we only need to consider
$\phi$ on a closed bounded interval, now composition of continuous functions is continuous, so the composition
is uniformly continuous due to the closed and boundedness of the image of f. Can I not just conclude from this that
the composition is Riemann integrable?

Comment: How do you get composition of continuous functions here? It is not given that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Ah thats what I was missing. Thankyou!